# Why does $\omega$ have no predecessor, and how do you generalize formulas that require the predecessor of ordinals to limit ordinals?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

$\omega$ is considered a limit ordinal, and an ordinal is considered a limit ordinal if and only if it has no predecessor, however, what about $\omega-1$?

And since limit ordinals cant have any predecessors then how do you extend the following,

$$_\beta N=\bigcup_{\alpha}\;_{\beta-1} N_\alpha$$
Because according to the rules of limit ordinals if $\beta$ is a limit ordinal there shouldn't exist, $\beta-1$. So how would you generalize the formula for $_\beta N$ for all ordinals?

Comment: What is $\omega-1$?

Comment: Usually you do *not* generalize formulas that apply to ordinals that have predecessors to those that do not have them! You usually do something different from the latter — this is how most transfinite induction arguments work, for example.

Comment: Oh, well then how would you do something different for such limit-ordinals?

Comment: If you read a couple of simple transfinite induction proofs, that should give you an idea for how to treat limit ordinals. Basically, they constitute a third, separate part of the proof, next to the base case and the classic induction step.

Comment: Just solved my problem.